# GCC installed but command not found

Tags: gcc, zsh, gcc-warning, oh-my-zsh

I'm new to linux and I'm having a hard time trying to get this work.
I uninstalled and installed gcc a few times. Now when I run `gcc --version`, it still says `zsh: command not found`.

When I go to `/usr/local/bin` and run `ls -l` I find multiple versions of gcc

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ps032791  admin                             33 Jul  2  2014 c++-4.6 -> ../Cellar/gcc46/4.6.4/bin/c++-4.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ps032791  admin                             33 Apr  6 11:58 c++-4.7 -> ../Cellar/gcc47/4.7.3/bin/c++-4.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ps032791  admin                             33 Apr  6 15:27 c++-4.8 -> ../Cellar/gcc/4.8.3_1/bin/c++-4.8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ps032791  admin                             32 Apr  6 15:19 cloog -> ../Cellar/cloog/0.18.1/bin/cloog
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ps032791  admin                             33 Jul  2  2014 cpp-4.6 -> ../Cellar/gcc46/4.6.4/bin/cpp-4.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ps032791  admin                             33 Apr  6 11:58 cpp-4.7 -> ../Cellar/gcc47/4.7.3/bin/cpp-4.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ps032791  admin                             33 Apr  6 15:27 cpp-4.8 -> ../Cellar/gcc/4.8.3_1/bin/cpp-4.8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ps032791  admin                             28 May 29  2014 erb -> ../Cellar/ruby/2.1.2/bin/erb
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ps032791  admin                             33 Jul  2  2014 g++-4.6 -> ../Cellar/gcc46/4.6.4/bin/g++-4.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ps032791  admin                             33 Apr  6 11:58 g++-4.7 -> ../Cellar/gcc47/4.7.3/bin/g++-4.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ps032791  admin                             33 Apr  6 15:27 g++-4.8 -> ../Cellar/gcc/4.8.3_1/bin/g++-4.8
-rw-r--r--  1 ps032791  admin                              0 Apr  6 13:23 gcc-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ps032791  admin                             33 Jul  2  2014 gcc-4.6 -> ../Cellar/gcc46/4.6.4/bin/gcc-4.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ps032791  admin                             33 Apr  6 11:58 gcc-4.7 -> ../Cellar/gcc47/4.7.3/bin/gcc-4.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ps032791  admin                             33 Apr  6 15:27 gcc-4.8 -> ../Cellar/gcc/4.8.3_1/bin/gcc-4.8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ps032791  admin                             36 Apr  6 11:58 gcc-ar-4.7 -> ../Cellar/gcc47/4.7.3/bin/gcc-ar-4.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ps032791  admin                             36 Apr  6 15:27 gcc-ar-4.8 -> ../Cellar/gcc/4.8.3_1/bin/gcc-ar-4.8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ps032791  admin                             36 Apr  6 11:58 gcc-nm-4.7 -> ../Cellar/gcc47/4.7.3/bin/gcc-nm-4.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ps032791  admin                             36 Apr  6 15:27 gcc-nm-4.8 -> ../Cellar/gcc/4.8.3_1/bin/gcc-nm-4.8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ps032791  admin                             40 Apr  6 11:58 gcc-ranlib-4.7 -> ../Cellar/gcc47/4.7.3/bin/gcc-ranlib-4.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ps032791  admin                             40 Apr  6 15:27 gcc-ranlib-4.8 -> ../Cellar/gcc/4.8.3_1/bin/gcc-ranlib-4.8
```

I ran 'brew doctor', and I get the following output,

```
Warning: You have MacPorts or Fink installed:
  /opt/local/bin/port

This can cause trouble. You don't have to uninstall them, but you may want to
temporarily move them out of the way, e.g.

  sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports

Warning: Your Homebrew is outdated.
You haven't updated for at least 24 hours, this is a long time in brewland!
To update Homebrew, run `brew update`.

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

    gcc48

Warning: You have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew
If this a surprise to you, then you should stash these modifications.
Stashing returns Homebrew to a pristine state but can be undone
should you later need to do so for some reason.
    cd /usr/local/Library && git stash && git clean -d -f

Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

    erb
    gem
    git
    git-cvsserver
    git-receive-pack
    git-shell
    git-upload-archive
    git-upload-pack
    irb
    rake
    rdoc
    ri
    ruby
    testrb

Consider setting your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin. Here is a one-liner:
    echo export PATH='/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

I tried running `echo export PATH='/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile`, restarted the terminal and again ran `brew doctor`, it still complains the same thing. I'm totally lost here. Can someone guide me with this? What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are using `zsh`, but modify `.bash_profile`. that probably does not fit

Comment: you may have gcc installed, but you don't have a symlink named `gcc` pointing at one of those executes. pick whichever gcc version you want, and make a symlink. e.g. `ln /usr/bin/gcc /path/to/cellar/gcc-4.8/gcc`

Comment: I ran, `ln /usr/bin/gcc /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.8.3_1/bin/gcc-4.8` and It says `ln: /usr/bin/gcc: No such file or directory`. I traversed to `/usr/bin` and I wasnt able to find gcc either

Answer (score 1):

You are not configuring the correct config file. Check this out:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Configuring_.24PATH

Check that gcc is installed correctly:

```
brew install gcc
brew link gcc48
```

Create an alias to whatever link brew created and put it in your .zshrc

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ls cpp*
ls c++*

alias gcc=/usr/local/bin/<whatever_link_you_found>
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me fix the PATH issue. But still not able to link gcc :(

Comment: Run `which gcc` and `gcc --version` . What's the output of those two command? What distro are you using?

Comment: it says `gcc not found`. I think I have to make a symlink like the previous comment. I tried doing that too.. Refer to my above comment

Comment: Wait a second, I thought you fixed the PATH issue? Switch to bash ( `bash') and then run the same 2 commands.

Comment: I got the same output

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74588/discussion-between-ventsyv-and-user3438489).